# parent view does not update the frame in auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I could not update the view frame in auto layout.
[image: here is the result while debugging the auto layout]

[image: Here is the constraints for vwLabelsAndInfoButtonContainer.]

[image: Here is the constraints for txtInfo]

[image: Here is the constraints for btnRouteMe]

```
[self setNeedsLayout];
[self.txtInfo setFont:WWLATOBLACK(15)];
[self.txtInfo setTextColor:ColorFromRGB(COLOR_CALLOUTINFO)];
self.txtInfo.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
self.txtInfo.text = self.result[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",SERVER_NAME, [LocalizationHelper getExtForLocale]]];
self.txtInfo.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: use Stack view, or manually calculate and set the frame of superview

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking, but you shouldn't update `frame` when you are using autolayout; you need to update the constraints.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have modified my question pls check. the code below the image is that I used for update my view.

Comment: Is the problem that the red person box isn't on the right?  It still isn't clear what the problem is

Comment: @Paulw11 yes the red person box should be on the right. and want to reduce the width of the vwLabelsAndInfoButtonContainer. Actually It should update the width of vwLabelsAndInfoButtonContainer and it's parents view automatically. isn't it?

Comment: Then you need the trailing constraint for `Btn route me` to "=12", not ">= 12"

Comment: After fixing it to 12, the width of txtInfo is bigger but the with of the parent view is not changed. ![Valid XHTML](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6PEjy4xzu1E/WVSDVE06i1I/AAAAAAAADM0/PhPCNhR2cYI30KBfF6yVPGQYYqZrs2jgwCL0BGAYYCw/h228/Screen%2BShot%2B2017-06-29%2Bat%2B12.31.24%2BPM.png).

Comment: @Paulw11 Actually I want to populate the UI lie this ![Valid XHTML](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-a-XneqVPIrQ/WUzn5-UMH4I/AAAAAAAAA3g/ZdboMay1XSwNtWCb9RN6fm27kwRETvw4wCL0BGAYYCw/h2048/a5db0ec4-101f-4d11-8205-f5fd6b54884a). I don't want the too much white space in my view.

Comment: How are you creating the view?

Comment: @Paulw11 I have a method called initWithReuseIdentifier. ![Valid XHTML](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-8BdfJxplnhM/WVSI8sL3f5I/AAAAAAAADNU/UehQHb93WlI-e7bKELkRsasT3J0l11odACL0BGAYYCw/h916/Screen%2BShot%2B2017-06-29%2Bat%2B12.57.46%2BPM.png).

Comment: I had a quick play around;  I got it to work by creating a view inside the root view of the xib file.  This view had top and leading constraints only.  Then I set top/bottom constraints for the label and constrained the button to the horizontal center of the label.  I then set this "inner" view as the `view` property of `files owner`.  That way I had a resizable view rather than the fixed size view of the xib file

Comment: @Paulw11 I am not very clear what u have done. I could not achieve what I want when I follow what you said.

Comment: I have uploaded my test app here - https://1drv.ms/f/s!Arv5SMgPRFc3i2Kucj2qwgF2pr58 I am not entirely sure how you have set yours up, but this is my guess as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Paulw11Now I realised It is not because of the autolayout problem. I am extending the MGLAnnotation from Mapbox to make the custom annotation in my project. But MapBox did not support to use the xib. That's why I have loaded the xib using its name and render it's components using tag. That causes the problems such as we could not use the layout from xib. Thanks for your help.